# How to check command results count for a command in p4?

Tags: perforce

When using p4 commands, like p4 sync, sometimes the maxresults limit is hit and the operation is cancelled. My first thought was that the MaxResults means the number of files that will be synced but results count is something different.

```
Request too large (over 1800000); see 'p4 help maxresults'.
```

When my command exceeds the limit I get the message. Is there a way to check results count for the command that does not exceed the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-Zdbstat` global option flag.  For example:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -Zdbstat sync -nq ...
--- db.counters
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 0/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 1+0+0 0+0
---   peek count 1 wait+held total/max 0ms+0ms/0ms+0ms
--- db.user
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 1+0+0 0+0
--- db.group
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+2 0+0
--- db.stream
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+3+3 0+0
--- db.domain
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 1+0+0 0+0
--- db.view
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+6 0+0
--- db.have
---   pages in+out+cached 7+0+6
---   locks read/write 0/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+260 0+0
---   peek count 1 wait+held total/max 0ms+0ms/0ms+0ms
--- db.revdx
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+1 0+0
--- db.revhx
---   pages in+out+cached 12+0+11
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+261 0+0
--- db.rev
---   pages in+out+cached 1+0+1
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 0+0
--- db.revtx
---   pages in+out+cached 1+0+1
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 0+0
--- db.working
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 0/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+2 0+0
---   peek count 1 wait+held total/max 0ms+0ms/0ms+0ms
--- db.trigger
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+1 0+0
--- db.protect
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+5 0+0
--- db.monitor
---   pages in+out+cached 4+4+2
---   locks read/write 0/2 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 2+0
```

The `MaxResults` setting is a cap on the results returned by the database queries within the Perforce server, not the final results returned by the command.  See `p4 help maxresults` for more information on how those result counts can be estimated for specific commands.